# Asp:Label is not shown when visible is set to true?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple web form which has a couple list boxes and a search button.  When the button is clicked, it returns a DataSet.  If the dataset contains records, I set the asp:label which is initially set to false to true, but this is not happening.  If the dataset has records and the visible property is set to true, the label still does not show up.

I have also tried putting the label and a couple other controls in an html table and setting a runat="server" attribute on the table and changing the visibility on that, but it does not show either.

Here is aspx code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSortBy" runat="server" Text="Sort By:" Visible="false">   
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList
                        ID="ddlSortBy" 
                        runat="server" 
                        AutoPostBack="True" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSortBy_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Gross">Gross</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Population">Population</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is simplified code behind when a button is clicked:

```
public void GetData()
{
    DataView dv = GetReportData().DefaultView;

    if(dv.ToTable().Rows.Count > 0)
     {
        lblSortBy.Visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
        lblSortBy.Visible = false;
     }
  }
```

I have a couple Update Panels around some ListBoxes and a GridView, but not the Label and Dropdown.  Would this cause an issue?

I did a test, I set a label that was in an update panel to false if records were found and the label disappeared, so it is working if it is in an update panel.

Comment: For usability, you should setting the AssociatedControlId to ddlSortBy so it gets rendered as an actual <label> rather than a span.

Comment: <label> tags are semantically linked to their controls. When you click them, they send focus to the associated control. This is especially useful for checkboxes, since the control is so small. They are also helpful for screenreaders.

Comment: Where/when is the GetData() method being called from?

Comment: Is the button inside an updatepanel or not? If it's not, and pressing it causes a full postback, then the updatepanels shouldn't matter.

Comment: You've verified that GetReportData() is in fact returning rows?

Comment: GetReportData is returning rows and the button is inside an UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your label should exist on an updatepanel, because as far as the static HTML page is concerned, the one and only time that your current label exists, it's set to be not visible.  You would have to reload the whole page to make it visible again.

Comment: Your label, outside of an updatepanel, is not asynchronous.  In other words you can't update a label that's already displayed on an end users computer, without refreshing the whole page.  If the label is on an updatepanel, you can.

Answer (score 6):

If the button is inside an UpdatePanel, then the Table, Label, etc. also have to be inside an UpdatePanel to get updated. Otherwise only the contents of the UpdatePanel get updated when clicking the button (this is what's called [partial page-rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx)).

So if the button is in an UpdatePanel, you have two possibilities to solve the problem:

1. put the table, Label, DropDownList etc. into the same UpdatePanel
2. or put them in another UpdatePanel and set the UpdateMode of that property to Always, so that it gets updated, even if a Postback was initiated by a control within another UpdatePanel.

See [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

- You just need runat="server" on the label itself; though Visible should default to True.
- Make sure you add a ForeColor to avoid mixing it in w/ background.
- Debug to ensure your label has content and it's not in another control whose Visible=False.

Comment: It already has content and the forecolor is black with a white background.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are gonna hide the ddl as well if there is no data. Have you tried putting a panel around both of them and setting its visibility to true

if you are returning rows and your button is in an updatepanel, then is your label and ddl in that updatepanel as well

Comment: but I am setting it the visibility to true if records are found.

Comment: have you debugged it to make sure it is actually setting the value?

Comment: k I was just wondering why is your dataview getting its data from the GetData function which is the name of your function above. Is this a mistake or just shorthand for example

Comment: It is just a shorthand example.  Basically it returns a DataSet.

Comment: also have you tried setting its visibility to true and just setting it to false if there are no rows

Comment: Just tried a panel. It did not work.  Could one reason be that I have some UpdatePanels around some other controls.  Would that cause issues?

Comment: it could but it is hard to tell without knowing more

Comment: I have done the pretty much the same thing before though and I had an update panel and had no issues

Comment: I did a test, I set a label that was in an update panel to false if records were found and the label disappeared, so it is working if it is in an update panel.

Comment: I would still recommend using the panel though instead if doing them both separately

Comment: Yes, I just tried and it works when I put the panel in an update panel.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is changing visible and is the parent container of the label I don't believe it is necessary to change the label's visibility at all as it should always be set to visible.

Comment: I know, I was just experimenting to see whether it was an asp.net control or any control.  That is why you see the label set to false, but in reality if I have the table visible, I would just have the label's visibility default.

Answer (score -2):

thanks its really useful, put Lable in a update panel.

```
        <ContentTemplate>
       <table>
           <tr>
                <td>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkNM" runat="server" Text="Learn>" BackColor="Transparent" style=" color: #6699FF;text-decoration-color:none;border:none;font-size:x-large" OnClick="LinkNM_Click"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                  <asp:Label ID="lblChapterName"  runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" style=" color: #6699FF;text-decoration-color:none;border:none;font-size:x-large" ></asp:Label>

                                </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
             </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFileUpload" />
        </Triggers>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```