# ImageButton event not firing inside Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

This is sort of a follow-up to my question here:

[Asp:Label is not shown when visible is set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534045/asplabel-is-not-shown-when-visible-is-set-to-true)

In the above question, I had a few controls where the visibility was not being set to false because they were not in an `UpdatePanel`.  Once I put the controls inside an `UpdatePanel`, the toggling of visibility worked, but this has caused me another problem.  I have an `ImageButton` that exports to excel.  When the button was not in an `UpdatePanel`, the click event fired, but now that I put it inside an `UpdatePanel`, the click event does not fire.

I also have a dropdown which works fine.  I am thinking it has something to do with the fact that the `ImageButton` does not have an `AutoPostBack` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have associated the Image Button to a PostBackTrigger on the UpdatePanel.  If you are exporting to Excel using something similar to [Matt Berseth's method](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html), you have to have this trigger for the export to work.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem. In my case, `ImageButtons` are inside a repeater which is bound to a `updatepanel`. But I used `Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(ImageButton)` in the code behind within `ItemDataBound` method of the repeater and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Add `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` to your update panel. Works if you have master pages.

If your update panel is in master you cannot add triggers.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a datalist with an imagebutton in the itemTemplate, the trigger is not required but `causeValidation = false` is.

Answer (score 0):

No, ImageButtons don't have AutoPostBack: they don't need them any more than regular buttons do.

That behaviour sounds pretty weird. I'd say the first thing to try would be to change the asp:ImageButton into an asp:Button and see if that changes the behaviour. If not, the fact that it's an ImageButton is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the imagebutton with a menu (which contains a single menu-item) and set the imageurl property thereof.

Answer (score 0):

```
myImagebutton.OnClientClick = "return true;";
```

Answer (score 0):

change the 'CausesValidation' attribute to false.