# can not access control inside asp.net updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use this official sample from Microsoft:

When I try to access the MyLabel from codebehind in the click event the MyLabel is NULL.

Why this?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="PageScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" Text="Click Me" runat="server" onClick="MyButton_Clicked" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
<Triggers> 
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MyButton" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="MyLabel" Text="OldText" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>




private void MyButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {   
  MyLabel.Text = "NewText!";
 }
```

**UPDATE** This code does not work Why? The MyLabel is always NULL on server side ??

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="xx">  
  </asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:ImageButton OnClick="OnClickRefreshButton" ID="RefreshImageButton" runat="server" Width="100px" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server"> 
    <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RefreshImageButton" EventName="Click" /> 
    </Triggers> 
    <asp:ContentTemplate> 
      <asp:Label ID="MyLabel" Text="OldText" runat="server" />
    </asp:ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>  
</asp:Content>

protected void OnClickRefreshButton(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
        {       

            MyLabel.Text = "NewText!";
        }
```

Comment: Hi there, try to put the button and the label "inside" the update panel.

Comment: The button is already in the updatepanel. When I put the button there then I get this exception: A control with ID 'RefreshImageButton' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'MyUpdatePanel'. 
Description

Comment: try to take this `<asp:Button ID="MyButton" Text="Click Me" runat="server" onClick="MyButton_Clicked" />` and put it under the label inside `<ItemTemplate>` and then close it `</ItemTemplate>` - so it should be <asp:Label ID="MyLabel" Text="OldText" runat="server" /> and then the itemtemplate then the button.

Comment: ItemTemplate??? this can not be put inside a contentTemplate. Are you sure you know asp.net? Its not WPF here... ;-)

Comment: LOL, you are right I wasn't on my working station so i thought it something like that sorry :) i posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the function to `protected` and not `private`, it worked for me. hope it solved your problem

Comment: Yes, this solutions is correct as we need to specify the access specifier as Protected

Comment: @TheNewOne It does not work, please see my updated question above.

Comment: maybe this would help to your updated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534438/imagebutton-event-not-firing-inside-update-panel

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust  `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to your `Updatepanel`

LInk : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx